# use IMU in differential robot?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Using an IMU sensor on a differential robot for navigation2d increases accuracy? is it worth?

Since the messages Sensor_msgs/Imu.msg do not consider the magnetic field ...

Has anyone ever made a comparison?
any experience report is welcome...

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319960/use-imu-in-differential-robot?/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2019-04-01**:
It is a de facto configuration I think..

**Comment by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on 2019-04-02**:
I do not understand, could you explain better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, an IMU can help you as compared to only wheel encoders! There's a more formal explanation which I think is worth digging into on your own time, but the major point is that an IMU's orientation/gryo drift is only proportional to time where wheel encoders are proportional to distance.

That's a *huge* result in my opinion making robotics much easier. Time is almost never the enemy but distance is. After moving 1 meter, you may have AMCL, ORB-SLAM, etc update your global position and then your drift is corrected. If you had wheel encoders only then the longer you go without an update the more wacky things are going to get. Versus having an IMU you can trust in the loop, you can now go a very long time without updates assuming practical limits.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2